# How can I break line in this type of string?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

Here is the code of python. I am trying to return the p variable to web page but on web page whole string is showing in one line

```
    for k, v in sim_sorted:
    if v >= 0.7 or str(q) in str(documents_clean[k]):
        p = f"""News is Valid                                                    
                similarity values: {v}   
                Headline: {documents_clean[k]}  
                Source: {df1.Link[k]}"""
        break
    elif v < 0.7 or str(q) not in str(documents_clean[k]):
        p ="Remarks: News is Invalid"
        break
return p
```

here is the HTML code:

```
      {% if result %}
      <center><strong>Prediction : {{result}}</strong></center>
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: i am retruning this p variable:  for k, v in sim_sorted:
        if v >= 0.7 or str(q) in str(documents_clean[k]):
            p = f"""News is Valid                                                    
                    similarity values: {v}   
                    Headline: {documents_clean[k]}  
                    Source: {df1.Link[k]}"""
            break
        elif v < 0.7 or str(q) not in str(documents_clean[k]):
            p ="Remarks: News is Invalid"
            break

Comment: Please edit the question to add this detail instead of posting as a commend. These things will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the p variable is going in the `{{ result }}`. In that case, Jinja is going to take the string p, and replace the `{{ result }}` with the string. This will in turn be rendered as HTML, so you need to treat the string as if it is HTML.

Try putting a line break tag '`<br>`' after each line in the string, like this:

```
p = f"""News is Valid <br>                                              
        similarity values: {v}<br>   
        Headline: {documents_clean[k]}  <br>
        Source: {df1.Link[k]}<br>"""
```